# Recommended way to run a web server on demand, with auto-shutdown (on AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate

I am trying to find the best way to architect a low cost solution to provide an on-demand web server for a certain amount of time.
The context is as follows: I have some large amount of data sitting on S3. From time to time, users will want to consult that data. I've written a Flask app that can display the data in a nice way for them. Beign poorly written, it really only accepts a single user session at the time. Currently therefore they have to download the Flask app and run it on their own machine.

I would like to find a way for users to request a cloud-based web server that would run the Flask app (through a docker container for example) on-demand, and give them access to it quickly, without having to do much if anything on their own machine.
Every user wanting to view the data would have their own web server created on demand (to avoid multiple users sharing the same web server, which wouldn't work with my Flask app)
Critically, and in order to avoid cost, the web server would terminate itself automatically after some (configurable) idle time (possibly with the Flask app informing the user that it's about to shut down, so that they can "renew" the lease).

Initially I thought that maybe AWS Fargate would be good: it can run docker instances, is quite configurable in terms of CPU/disk it can get (my Flask app is resource-hungry), and at least on paper could be used in a way that there is zero cost when users are not consulting the data (bar S3 costs naturally).  But it's when it comes to the detail that I'm not sure...

- How to ensure that every new user gets their own Fargate instance?
- How to shut-down the instance automatically after idle time?
- Is Fargate quick enough in terms of boot time?

Comment: Your question is very broad and you have number of sub-question. I would suggest focussing only on a single, specific issue/sub-question, rather then on everything at once.

Comment: Lambda + API gateway seems to be the obvious solution here, but requires you to rewrite your code.

Comment: Since cost appears to be your critical factor, have you considered options that do not require a server? For example, could your app run once per day and generate reports for each user, which are then stored in Amazon S3? Users would simply retrieve the pre-created reports rather than having them generated on-the-fly.

Comment: @jordanm - lambda doesn’t have enough power, and the timeout is not flexible.

Comment: @john rotenstein - unfortunately the web app is very interactive, and there is no way of knowing in advance what the users will want to see. It’s typically also something users want to do straight after running the process that generates the data (I didn’t give any detail because it wasn’t relevant, but essentially an AWS Batch process)

Comment: In that case, it's really a matter of paying for a server so that your users can make use of your interactive app. If your traffic is low, you can pay for a low-cost server (a few cents per day), or perhaps even use an Amazon Lightsail instance, which has a fixed cost for the month including bandwidth. Lightsail is a nice way to run a simple app.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I can think is [AWS App Runner](https://aws.amazon.com/apprunner/). It's built on top of Fargate and it provides an intelligent scale out mechanism (probably you are not interested in this) as well as a scale to (almost) 0 capability. The way it works is that when the endpoint is solicited and it's doing work you pay for the entire fargate task (cpu/memory) you have selected in the configuration. If the endpoint is doing nothing you only pay for the memory (note the memory cost is roughly 20% of the entire cost so it's not scale to 0 but "quasi"). Checkout the pricing examples at the bottom of [this page](https://aws.amazon.com/apprunner/pricing/).
Please note you can further optimize costs by pausing/starting the endpoint (when it's paused you pay nothing) but in that case you need to create the logic that pauses/restarts it.

Another option you may want to explore is using Lambda [this way](http://it20.info/2021/11/running-the-stock-nginx-container-image-with-aws-lambda/) (which would allow you to use the same container image and benefit from the intrinsic scale to 0 of Lambda). But given your comment "Lambda doesn’t have enough power, and the timeout is not flexible" may be a show stopper.

Comment: Thanks very much for your input. The lambda+NGINX is a very interesting blog post, but as you say, pretty much a no-go for me. For starters, the lambda function would have to download GB of data from S3 (to have them local for fast processing)...

I'll look into App Runner. Never come across it

Comment: Cool happy to help. FYI (I don't know if this could change anything for you but) Lambda supports EFS (AWS' NFS compatible fully managed service). So if you can either host your files on EFS or download them "once" on EFS at one point, your Lambda won't need to download it everytime is starts (which would DEFINITELY be a NO NO). App Runner could be a good alternative (in general) though. Good luck!